# Getting count of open connections

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu-12.04, tcpdump, netstat

I have automated the deployment of my application via fabric and have a new step that I need to add where I take my application out of rotation in the load balancer then, watch inbound connections from the balancer until they go to 0. Problem is, I am not sure how to get the count of inbound connections.

I can use tcpdump to watch my port POSTs. However, this is kind of hard to use in fabric. What I would like is to just run a loop with a timer that keeps getting the number of active inbound connections and exits on 0. Has anybody done anything like this? Or maybe someone would know how I might be able to achieve this from the shell and I can put it in fabric?

Comment: `netstat` would probably be a good place to start...

Comment: Thanks. I am using netstat. The closest I can get is netstat -aln | grep ":80 \|:443 " which doesn't differentiate between inbound/outbound.

Comment: `netstat ... | awk '$4 ~ /:80/'` would find connections with port 80 on the local end (i.e. incoming), while `netstat ... | awk '$5 ~ /:80/` would find outgoing... At least on my system, where "Local Address" is the 4th column and "Foreign Address" is the 5th...

Comment: You rock! That did it! You should put it in the answer so I can close this and get you credit. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`netstat` is one of the simplest ways to get this information, however, as you have noted, simply using `grep` to parse the output of `netstat` yields sub-optimal results, because it will match both incoming and outgoing connections (at least without a sufficiently complex search expression, or preprocessing with `cut` or the like). I would suggest this route, instead:

```
netstat -ap | awk '$1 == "tcp" && $4 ~ /:(80|443)$/' | wc -l
```

This will count connections that are TCP-based, and the local end is connected to either port 80 or 443, which would correspond with incoming connections. Replace `$4` with `$5` in that to catch outgoing connections instead.

Comment: @Belegnar The only way that differs from the proposed command is not doing name resolution, so connections are listed with IP addresses instead of hostnames. Granted, that may be slightly more efficient, but it does not change the result materially.

Comment: result is totaly differs for `$5` because `-n` prevents port number resolution

`$ netstat -ap`

`tcp        0      0 192.168.1.1:39040      yandex.ru:https         ESTABLISHED 4588/firefox    `

`$ netstat -apn`

`tcp        0      0 192.168.1.1:51416      46.4.69.39:443          ESTABLISHED 4588/firefox    `

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working any more. The tcp part is working but the $4 and $5 aren't working even when I try to test them independentlly.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a slight change somewhere but, this is what's working now.

```
netstat -an | awk '$1 == "tcp" && $4 ~ /:(80|443)$/' | wc -l
netstat -an | awk '$1 == "tcp" && $5 ~ /:(80|443)$/' | wc -l
```

From the current netstat help, `-n means don't resolve names` but `-p only means display PID/Program name for sockets`. So, the check on `$4` and `$5` in the awk in the above solution would fail.

Additionally, the above command also returns closed ports and other unestablished connections. So, we should use this instead:

```
netstat -an | awk '$1 == "tcp" && $4 ~ /:(80|443)$/ && $6==ESTABLISHED' | wc -l
netstat -an | awk '$1 == "tcp" && $5 ~ /:(80|443)$/ && $6==ESTABLISHED' | wc -l
```

Additionally, this also works::

```
netstat -ap | awk '$1 == "tcp" && $4 ~ /:(http|https)$/' | wc -l
netstat -ap | awk '$1 == "tcp" && $5 ~ /:(http|https)$/' | wc -l
```